# Excel- Return value if date between two dates

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Ok so this is my first time here and I thought I had figured this out but I just cant, so hopefully you guys can help :)

I am trying to build a budget where my bills are deducted from my paycheck ahead of time.
We get paid every Thursday, I want to see what bills are taken out.

Heres what I have so far, a way to generate the Thursdays of every month and the dates for my bills
but whenever i try and IF AND function I get answers that are half right.

Please take a look and let me know what would be the best idea to do this.

```
Paychecks   Amount  Date            After bills
Paycheck 1          09/04/2014      $-   
Paycheck 2          09/11/2014      $-   
Paycheck 3          09/18/2014      $-   
Paycheck 4          09/25/2014      $-   
Subtotal    $0.00                    $0.00

Bills       Amount      Date
Rent        $331.00     09/01/2014
WF Card     $40.00      09/01/2014
US Bank     $40.00      09/06/2014
Reserve     $40.00      09/09/2014
Cap One     $60.00      09/15/2014
Cred One    $30.00      09/15/2014
Gym         $32.00      09/15/2014
Insuranc    $172.00     09/16/2014
Netflix     $8.53       09/23/2014
```

For example I would want Pay 1 to have all the bills from before the first to the 11th out
Pay 2 would have all the bills from the 11th taken out to the 18th taken out
etc etc

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use, I'm assuming your bills are on a sheet called  'Bills', columns A, B, C. Also, I'm gonna assume that if you get paid on the 4th, you pay bills up to the 10th, as your explanation may lead to doubling up of bill payments.

```
=B2-SUMIFS(Bills!$B:$B,Bills!$C:$C,">="&$C2,Bills!$C:$C,"<="&$C2+6)
```